# Changing font in a Console window in .NET

Tags: c#, console-application

I have built a neat little Console app which basically interacts with ASP.NET projects on a users machine. I have a really trivial need, all I need to do is before I show the Console window, I need to have it a black background, a lime green foreground and a Lucida font. I could achieve the color part by using the static methods of Console class. Although there is nothing in the class which talks about changing fonts? Has anyone been able to change Console font programatically?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be just easier to make it a WinForms app? If its logic is well separated and loosely coupled, you should be able to only add a single TextBox (or a RichTextBox?) to an empty Form and be basically done. I would prefer such app better than a customized Console app.

Answer (score 4):

Please don't do that on an application that is meant to be used from other users, unless they request this feature. Consolas is the only font for consoles on my system :p

You can try to change the properties of the link that opens the console (or the executable), but that is a local setting if I'm right. This is likely the thing you want if it's just for running the app on your system. I'm not sure how you can change these programmatically.

Since Vista, there's `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`, which may do what you want, if you can get it to work with the Console class. Did I mention I will hate you for that if the app ever comes to my system? ;)

Comment: Lol. I am not going to let you use my little Super app :). In that case, I should not even change the colors then.

Comment: Not in general, but colors can also be use to improve formatting (like PowerShell does, for example, with errors in red) :)

Answer (score 2):

The console window is a pretty basic environment. Whilst it's possible to change the font in most recent versions of Windows using unmanaged Win32 API calls, it's not supported through a managed API.

Font colour, however, can be set using the [`Console.ForegroundColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor.aspx) property.

Arguably, you shouldn't be trying to exert so much control over a console window as it's intended to be a simple text-only interface. If you want to have absolute control over the typeface used, you should consider upgrading to a Windows application, as this will let you trivially create a text window and do whatever you want to the fonts and colours in use.

Comment: This is only partially true. You can't change the font for single characters, but you can for the entire console.

Comment: If you see the properties window for a Console, there are 2 fonts available. Why would the .NET framework not be able to change the font and be able to change colors!

Comment: @OregonGhost: Can you let me know how would change the font programatically for the entire Console then?

Comment: @theraneman: Because the color is changed by putting codes in the output of your program, whereas the font is changed by changing the settings of `cmd.exe`. The two are vastly different.

Comment: Console.ForegroundColor changes the color of the following output, not of the entire console window. This is different from setting the default console color from the console properties page.

Comment: @theraneman: Go read my answer. I don't know though how you can change the console properties programmatically (maybe via registry access), but the option I mentioned may be all you need anyway.