# Change console text kerning in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, console-application, kerning

I'm trying to make each letter a "square" essentially, so each letter is no more tall than it is wide, in vb.net. Is this possible? If so, how? I can't seem to find anything, and I've been searching hard.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just use a fixed size font ? Or create your own font ?

Comment: Okay, how do you change the font on the console then?

Comment: @Cyclone, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802600/changing-font-in-a-console-window-in-net

Comment: Right click the icon on the window title bar, click properties, font. There you go.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows API has a function called [SetCurrentConsoleFontEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which you could [pinvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx). It accepts a width and height, font etc. Depending on how it handles these you may also need to make and add a 'square font' to the registry list of allowed fonts (example of adding a new font to the console [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsingConsolasAsTheWindowsConsoleFont.aspx).)