# How do I write special characters (0x80..0x9F) to the Windows console?

Tags: c#, character-encoding, console, windows-console

I would like to have this code:

```
System.Console.Out.WriteLine ("œil");
```

display `œil` instead of `oil` as it does in my test program.

The `Console.OutputEncoding` is set by default to `Western European (DOS)` (`CodePage` set to 850 and `WindowsCodePage` set to 1252) on my system. The character set contains the special OE and oe diphtongs (as can be seen on the [Wikipedia article on Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)) but somehow, I suspect that the characters not found in the [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) set get discarded/replaced.

Characters such as `â`, `ç`, etc. get properly displayed on the console, but any character in the extended 0x80 ... 0x9F range are not.

How can I properly display them on the console?

Comment: Very unusual to get code page 1252 on the console, it is almost always 437, the IBM PC OEM code page.  Which doesn't have a glyph for \u0153.  You can change the OutputEncoding but then you'll also have to change the console font.

Comment: Incidentally, "Western European (DOS)" is codepage 850, not 1252. It contains all of the characters from ISO 8859-1 (i.e. windows 1252's 0xA0-0xFF) which may have caused some confusion. The .NET function themselves use Unicode, but get translated (sometimes poorly) when written to the console with a non-truetype font selected.

Comment: I've clarified the code page issues; the `System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding` returns both a codepage and a Windows codepage and I confused both. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
System.Console.Out.WriteLine("œil");
```

Don't forget to select a font for your console window that supports the characters you need. This is a screen shot of my console window using the Consolas font.

[image]

Comment: Indeed, this does not work. On my Windows 7 x64, executing your code produces a cross followed by characters `ôil`.

Comment: Works fine for me. What font do you have in your console Window?

Comment: Be warned that Lucida Console has a lot of characters wrong. Use something else, for example Consolas.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802600/changing-font-in-a-console-window-in-net on how to change the font of a console in C# using interop.

Comment: The secret is indeed in the font... Using Consolas as the font makes the UTF8 output display properly, just like what David posted in his screenshot. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And by the way, here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939643/how-do-i-read-special-characters-0x80-0x9f-from-the-console-in-c (how do I read special characters back)

Answer (score 2):

You could set the output encoding on the console like this...

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: I guess I ended up commenting on a stale page :)

Comment: Yeah, I do it plenty myself +1