# How do I read special characters (0x80 ... 0x9F) from the Windows console in C#?

Tags: c#, character-encoding, console, windows-console

I've finally solved the issue of [writing special characters (0x80...0x9F) to the Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929763/how-do-i-write-special-characters-0x80-0x9f-to-the-windows-console) with the help of [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan):

1. The output encoding has to be set to UTF-8.
2. The font used by the console should be something like Consolas.

Now I'd like to be able to read back text which contains special characters found in the 0x80-0x9F range (using the Windows 1252 encoding), such as the EURO sign (€):

```
string text = System.Console.ReadLine ();
```

returns `null` whenever I type one of the special characters. I tried naively to set the `InputEncoding` to UTF8:

```
System.Console.InputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

but this does not help.

Comment: Not really a solution, but i did find this [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/652017/bcl-reading-unicode-input-from-console-not-supported) bug report.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just write a GUI app? They handle Unicode very well.

Comment: try `System.Console.Read()`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the input code page of your console application to read those special characters.
There is a Win32 api called SetConsoleCP to set the input code page. In the following example I use Windows-1252 code page:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetConsoleCP(uint wCodePageID);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  SetConsoleCP((uint)1252);
  Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
  System.Console.Out.WriteLine("œil"); 

  string euro = Console.In.ReadLine();

  Console.Out.WriteLine(euro);
}
```

**EDIT:**

AS L.B. suggested you could also use Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).

Here is the complete example without interop (note, you could also use Windows-1252 code page for output encoding:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.InputEncoding  = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
  Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
  System.Console.Out.WriteLine("œil"); 

  string euro = Console.In.ReadLine();

  Console.Out.WriteLine(euro);
}
```

**END EDIT**

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Why to use interop?  doesn't `Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");` work?

Comment: @L.B You are right. I've updated my answer to show your suggested solution.

Answer (score -3):

Euro sign(€):Unicode 0x20ac also UTF-8 byte sequence 0xE2 0x82 0xAC.
not range of 0x80-0x9F.

```
char Euro = Convert.ToChar(0x20ac);
Console.WriteLine(Euro);
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(0x80));
```

command line input this

```
>csc sample.cs
>chcp 65001
```

The font change TrueTypeFont("Consoleas" or "Lucida Console" select) at Command Line window propaty (font tab)

```
>sample
€
?
```

(?:enclosed in square).
charactor code check the font palette case 0x80-0x9F.It has not been assigned a Unicode-enabled font.

Comment: He is already able to write unicode to the console, this is about reading it.

Comment: € *is* in the 0x80-0x9f range in some encodings (e.g. 8859-15). Also, wtf is the font palette case?

Comment: @J.Kommer Well, in my example is irrelevant parts.Its delete.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, if your question is to me, then please use the comment notification system covered in the SO documentation.