# How can I display special symbols like flowers symboles on CMD with C#?

Tags: c#, encoding, command-line

According to name of topic I tried to display some special symbols on CMD with C#,but  when I use for example *\u273F* to display a flower,the result is only *?* characters!!!
I changed the cmd font to *lucida console* and I used these line but none of them was helpful.

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
```

What can I do else? I searched a lot on the net,but I didn't take any way to solve my issue!!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace UniCodes
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
        Console.WriteLine("This is a list of unicodes of  some characters"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0000"+" \t"+"\u0000"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0001"+" \t"+"\u0001"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0002"+" \t"+"\u0002"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0003"+" \t"+"\u0003"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0004"+" \t"+"\u0004"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0005"+" \t"+"\u0005"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0006"+" \t"+"\u0006"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0007"+" \t"+"\u0007"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0008"+" \t"+"\u0008"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0009"+" \t"+"\u0009"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0010"+" \t"+"\u0010"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0020"+" \t"+"\u0020"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0030"+" \t"+"\u0030"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0040"+" \t"+"\u0040"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0050"+" \t"+"\u0050"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0060"+" \t"+"\u0060"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0070"+" \t"+"\u0070"+
        "\n"+ @"\U0080"+" \t"+"\u0080"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0090"+" \t"+"\u0090"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0011"+" \t"+"\u0011"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0012"+" \t"+"\u0012"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0013"+" \t"+"\u0013"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0014"+" \t"+"\u0014"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0015"+" \t"+"\u0015"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0016"+" \t"+"\u0016"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0017"+" \t"+"\u0017"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0018"+" \t"+"\u0018"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0019"+" \t"+"\u0019"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0021"+" \t"+"\u0021"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0022"+" \t"+"\u0022"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0023"+" \t"+"\u0023"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0024"+" \t"+"\u0024"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0025"+" \t"+"\u0025"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0026"+" \t"+"\u0026"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0027"+" \t"+"\u0027"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0028"+" \t"+"\u0028"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0029"+" \t"+"\u0029"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0031"+" \t"+"\u0031"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0032"+" \t"+"\u0032"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0033"+" \t"+"\u0033"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0034"+" \t"+"\u0034"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0035"+" \t"+"\u0035"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0036"+" \t"+"\u0036"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0037"+" \t"+"\u0037"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0038"+" \t"+"\u0038"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0039"+" \t"+"\u0039"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0041"+" \t"+"\u0041"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0042"+" \t"+"\u0042"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0043"+" \t"+"\u0043"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0044"+" \t"+"\u0044"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0045"+" \t"+"\u0045"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0046"+" \t"+"\u0046"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0047"+" \t"+"\u0047"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0048"+" \t"+"\u0048"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0049"+" \t"+"\u0049"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0051"+" \t"+"\u0051"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0052"+" \t"+"\u0052"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0053"+" \t"+"\u0053"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0054"+" \t"+"\u0054"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0055"+" \t"+"\u0055"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0056"+" \t"+"\u0056"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0057"+" \t"+"\u0057"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0058"+" \t"+"\u0058"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0059"+" \t"+"\u0059"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0061"+" \t"+"\u0061"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0062"+" \t"+"\u0062"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0063"+" \t"+"\u0063"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0064"+" \t"+"\u0064"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0065"+" \t"+"\u0065"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0066"+" \t"+"\u0066"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0067"+" \t"+"\u0067"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0068"+" \t"+"\u0068"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0069"+" \t"+"\u0069"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0071"+" \t"+"\u0071"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0072"+" \t"+"\u0072"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0073"+" \t"+"\u0073"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0074"+" \t"+"\u0074"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0075"+" \t"+"\u0075"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0076"+" \t"+"\u0076"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0077"+" \t"+"\u0077"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0078"+" \t"+"\u0078"+
        "\n"+ @"\u0079"+" \t"+"\u0079"+
        "\n"+ @"\u000A"+" \t"+"\u000A"+
        "\n"+ @"\u000B"+" \t"+"\u000B"+
        "\n"+ @"\u000C"+" \t"+"\u000C"+
        "\n"+ @"\u000D"+" \t"+"\u000D"+
        "\n"+ @"\u000E"+" \t"+"\u000E"+
        "\n"+ @"\u000F"+" \t"+"\u000F"+
        "\n"+ @"\u000a"+" \t"+"\u000a"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00A0"+" \t"+"\u00A0"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00A1"+" \t"+"\u00A1"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00A2"+" \t"+"\u00A2"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00A3"+" \t"+"\u00A3"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00A4"+" \t"+"\u00A4"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00A5"+" \t"+"\u00A5"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00A6"+" \t"+"\u00A6"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00A7"+" \t"+"\u00A7"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00A8"+" \t"+"\u00A8"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00A9"+" \t"+"\u00A9"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00B1"+" \t"+"\u00B1"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00B2"+" \t"+"\u00B2"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00B3"+" \t"+"\u00B3"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00B4"+" \t"+"\u00B4"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00B5"+" \t"+"\u00B5"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00B6"+" \t"+"\u00B6"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00B7"+" \t"+"\u00B7"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00B8"+" \t"+"\u00B8"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00B9"+" \t"+"\u00B9"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00C0"+" \t"+"\u00C0"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00C1"+" \t"+"\u00C1"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00E2"+" \t"+"\u00E2"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00E3"+" \t"+"\u00E3"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00E4"+" \t"+"\u00E4"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00E5"+" \t"+"\u00E5"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00D1"+" \t"+"\u00D1"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00F2"+" \t"+"\u00F2"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00F5"+" \t"+"\u00F5"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00F4"+" \t"+"\u00F4"+
        "\n"+ @"\u00F3"+" \t"+"\u00F3"+
        "\n"+ @"\u001a"+" \t"+"\u001a"+
        "\n"+ @"\u001B"+" \t"+"\u001B"+
        "\n"+ @"\u001C"+" \t"+"\u001C"+
        "\n"+ @"\u001D"+" \t"+"\u001D"+
        "\n"+ @"\u001E"+" \t"+"\u001E"+
        "\n"+ @"\u002a"+" \t"+"\u002a"+
        "\n"+ @"\u003a"+" \t"+"\u003a"+
        "\n"+ @"\u004a"+" \t"+"\u004a"+
        "\n"+ @"\u005a"+" \t"+"\u005a"+
        "\n"+ @"\u006a"+" \t"+"\u006a"+
        "\n"+ @"\u007a"+" \t"+"\u007a"+
        "\n"+ @"\u2070"+" \t"+"\u2070"+
        "\n"+ @"\u221A"+" \t"+"\u221A"+
        "\n"+ @"\u2211"+" \t"+"\u2211"+
        "\n"+ @"\u2229"+" \t"+"\u2229"+
        "\n"+ @"\u221E"+" \t"+"\u221E"+
        "\n"+ @"\u263c"+" \t"+"\u263c"+
        "\n"+ @"\u2261"+" \t"+"\u2261"+
        "\n"+ @"\u2248"+" \t"+"\u2248"+
        "\n"+ @"\u2320"+" \t"+"\u2320"+
        "\n" + @"\u273F" + " \t" + "\u273F"
        );
            Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write unicode chars to console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-chars-to-console)

Comment: Thanks dear,but I read that topic before too.I will put my code here to see.

Comment: Is there a use-case for something like this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: According to Character Map here, Lucida Console does not contain a glyph for U+273F: start by ensuring the font you are testing with has the glyphs you need.

Comment: @Sahba.ph Understood, sorry, read only the title and not the question body.

Comment: Based on the comment from @Richard, it should be just a matter of changing the console font. See this: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2009/07/23/changing-console-fonts/ (taken from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802600/changing-font-in-a-console-window-in-net). You should read all the answers and warnings in the other SO question.

Comment: @Sahba.ph just a tip: in (non-Indian) English, [you shouldn't address anyone except your wife as "dear"](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3584684/Indian-English-Words-to-avoid-dear.aspx).

Comment: @ Blorgbeard. Ohhhhh I'M SO SORRY !! I'm not Indian and "dear" in my language is a usual word to show our respect and attention to our addressed.I'm so sorry any one and thanks for this tip.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure it to use Unicode character set. Also, as Eugene says, here's a more explained answer:

[How to write Unicode characters to the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-chars-to-console)

Answer (score 0):

I installed some  monospaced-fonts with special characters, but none of them were suitable to introduce to CMD.

AND I understood that my asked(set a font like Wingdings font to CMD for have some lovely character on CMD) is an impossible action. however I'm glad to take this experience .

Thanks every one...