# Is it possible to adjust the distance between lines in the console?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am writing a small console game in visual studio, using .NET and c#, and I wish for the distance between each row in the console to be smaller than the default, for aesthetic purposes. Is this possible?

Comment: If you find a `Console.WriteLine` or similar in your code and you right click `Console` and go to definition you can see all the properties/methods of `Console`. It doesnt look to me like there is one for adjusting line height

Comment: You can change the console properties using the to left system menu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# modify console font, font size at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47014258/c-sharp-modify-console-font-font-size-at-runtime)