# C# Set console font and font size from runtime

Tags: c#, dll, struct, fonts, console-application

I am trying to create a [Rougelike](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/Nethack_releasing_a_djinni.png) in a console application.
I am wanting to set font and font size from runtime as MS Gothic and 36 respectively.

I have tried using the code `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx` found [HERE](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.SetCurrentConsoleFontEx).

I am having no luck editing the fields of the struct so I am guessing that the struct is Immutable? To work around this could I change the structs to classes or make the struct mutable?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; //required to import dll

namespace RPLike
{


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct COORD
    {
        public short X;
        public short Y;

        public COORD(short X, short Y)
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX
    {
        public COORD dwFontSize;
        public ushort FontFamily;

        UInt64 face0, face1, face2, face3, face4, face5, face6, face7;
    }


    class Program
    {
        COORD COORD = (18,36); //pixel dimensions of MS Gothic at 36 font size
        CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX FontFamily = 4; //MS Gothic is the 5th option of font

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(IntPtr ConsoleOutput, bool MaximumWindow, CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX ConsoleCurrentFontEx);
        //import the pointers required to edit console font.. I think?


        static void Main(string[] args)
```

I'm currently experiencing the Errors:

```
CS8179  Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple`2' is not defined or imported
CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type '(int, int)' to 'RPLike.COORD'
CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'RPLike.CONSOLE_FONT_INFO_EX'
```

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802600/changing-font-in-a-console-window-in-net) post mentions "Since Vista, there's SetCurrentConsoleFontEx, which may do what you want, if you can get it to work with the Console class." but doesn't describe or provide any examples of how to implement the function.

An alternative approach is listed at [THIS](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/118967/) forum post. My question is is this only applicable to c++ or can it be modified to work in c#?
void setFontSize(int FontSize)

```
{
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX info = {0};
    info.cbSize       = sizeof(info);
    info.dwFontSize.Y = FontSize; // leave X as zero
    info.FontWeight   = FW_NORMAL;
    wcscpy(info.FaceName, L"Lucida Console");
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), NULL, &info);
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing font in a Console window in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802600/changing-font-in-a-console-window-in-net)

Comment: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2009/07/23/changing-console-fonts/

Comment: @Link I address that post in my post. Hans could you post an answer with explanation of your link? Specifically explination of this line of code `[DllImport("kernel32")]
  private extern static bool SetConsoleFont(IntPtr hOutput, uint index);` Sorry but my knowledge is limited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible at the time (of October 2017), as there is no such property or method in the [C# Console Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console) that could fulfill your requirements.

I would like to quote a part of [this answer by Paul Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1802631/4733879):

> [...] If you want to have absolute control over the typeface used, you should consider upgrading to a Windows application, as this will let you trivially create a text window and do whatever you want to the fonts and colours in use.

So you may consider using Windows Forms instead, and emulate the "console" with a Label with [black background](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.background(v=vs.110).aspx) and your wished [font](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.fontfamily(v=vs.110).aspx)
 [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.fontsize(v=vs.110).aspx) (which also can be set over the Windows Forms designer, not just programmatically)

Comment: Well i'm glad you've given me a definitive not possible or else I'd be beating my head against the wall trying. Does Winforms add much complexity compared to console apps or would you say its similar to console apps just with extra functionality?
Also my code to my naive knowledge seems close to fulfilling my requirements would you be able to comment on why its impossible?

Comment: WinForms DOES add some complexity (not very hard to learn), as console in- and output is "just" text and WinForms has Forms, Labels, Buttons..., but it also adds a lot of powerful features (e.g. opening another form to show the inventory). It's not possible possible because the .NET Framework can't access the console settings GUI (where the font settings can be changed) and Microsoft would need to implement such an access to allow developers to change this properties.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you!