# Load custom font to Console C# .Net Framework

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, console, customization

Okay, I'm making a game..
I want to **load a custom font into the console** to draw graphics in my game. And the main thing is to load the font **programmatically** so that another user who launches my game can immediately see this very font, and not the standard consolas or somethisng else.

I already know how to change the font / font size.
I already know how to replace the standard console colors with the ones I need. But now I want to draw and upload my own font, is it possible?

*Of course I'm going to draw a monospaced (even square) font.*

Comment: why would you need a custom font in a console application? it makes no sense - console applications are not design for graphical user interfaces...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing font in a Console window in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802600/changing-font-in-a-console-window-in-net)

Comment: @tommy99 There is no an answer.
I'm making a roguelike for my dad, I definitely need to do this in the console.

Comment: why not do in WPF or windows forms? why console? it makes zero sense.

Comment: @tommy99 Just because I like doing things in the console, why are you trying to convince me? I just asked how to load a custom font

https://scontent-waw1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/130966230_436907887714925_3200288775112122481_o.jpg?_nc_cat=106&ccb=2&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_ohc=CIULj75OcugAX8qydbP&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-1.xx&oh=aae4af5afbb2121790eca753d2405f29&oe=5FF61980

Comment: Because sometimes the correct answer is "just don't do it like that". If you want to make a game, maybe use Unity - that's the C#-based environment which is specifically designed for games developers. Any kind of roguelike game is going to be pretty tricky to implement (and/or produce very suboptimal results) in the console, for a lot of different reasons. Use the right tool for the job. You wouldn't use a yard brush to paint a wall, would you?

Comment: You can try using a WinForm and Paint on the background using GDI+ API. Or use Unity.

Comment: So at runtime you're going to create a new font, then switch to it?  You can't install all these fonts ahead of time when you install your console app, then switch to them?

Comment: @DanCsharpster Oh, on the topic! Dude, I want to load my font to the console, I'll draw the font myself. And I also want another user, for example my dad, to be able to download / install my game and run it with this font immediately, without additional configuration.

Comment: If you want this on a Windows based console (I'm not sure if you specified) then you are kinda past what the console was meant for.  I'm not saying you couldn't do it.  With enough time and effort you could build yourself a Death Star. However, in this case I think your time might be better spent creating something like a console emulator in a browser then sharing a central database of fonts between all of the connected clients.  You're also going to need a console designer...in the console, right?  I dunno man.  Good luck!

Comment: @DanCsharpster Browser version is an interesting idea, thanks man

Comment: No problem.  I think something like Electron or Blazor WebAssembly, the latter of which would allow you to stay in C# land, would be a good candidate for this.